# Azure active directory - skip login prompt while authorize api call and get code

Tags: python, node.js, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an usecase which i need to read mails from outlook, as per the documentation i need to make 2 api calls as follows

1 https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

2 https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

In 1st api call, i have passed required parameters such as client_id,redirect_uri, response_type, scope

i can get access code while 1st api in web browser, while in postman i'm getting html code

is there any way to get access code programmatically?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), please refer to the section [`4. Get an access token`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token).

Here is my sample codes for Python and Node.js, and their results, as below.

## Python code using [`requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) package

```
import requests

tenant = "<your tenant id>"
url = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token"

client_id = "<your client id>"
client_secret = "<your client secret>"

body = {'client_id': client_id, 'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default', 'client_secret': client_secret, 'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}

r = requests.post(url, data=body)

json_text = r.text

import json
j = json.loads(json_text)
print('The json object of /token response =>', j)
access_token = j['access_token']
print('access_token =>', access_token)
```

[image]

## Node.js code using [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) package

```
const request = require('request');
const querystring = require('querystring');

const tenant = '<your tenant id>';
var url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;

var client_id = "<your client id>";
var client_secret = "<your client secret>";

var body = querystring.stringify({'client_id': client_id, 'scope': 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default', 'client_secret': client_secret, 'grant_type': 'client_credentials'});

request.post({
    headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    url:     url,
    body:    body
  }, function(error, response, body){
    console.log('The json object of /token response =>', body);
    var j = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log('access_token =>', j['access_token']);
  });
```

[image]